# Mobile friendly test cant access website

Tags: robots.txt, concrete5, concrete

I have a issue where website I developed using concrete5,

http://www.cavaliers.org.au/

cannot be access when doing a mobile friendly test through google:

https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly

I have a robot.txt at the root but I believe what is in their is correct:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /application/attributes
Disallow: /application/authentication
Disallow: /application/bootstrap
Disallow: /application/config
Disallow: /application/controllers
Disallow: /application/elements
Disallow: /application/helpers
Disallow: /application/jobs
Disallow: /application/languages
Disallow: /application/mail
Disallow: /application/models
Disallow: /application/page_types
Disallow: /application/single_pages
Disallow: /application/tools
Disallow: /application/views
Disallow: /blackhole/
```

Could anyone enlighten me on how I can resolve this issue. I've searched around and found very little.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When inspecting the code of the website, I notice the head tag is closed prematurely. (after a style-tag)

If you look at the source code of the website, you'll notice the div with id "fb-root" and the facebook app script is loaded before the doctype, html and head tag.

[image: homepage source code of the homepage]

This might cause issues with the mobile friendly test. Move the div and script to the correct location (probably before footer_required and closing the body tag)